# Could it be a problem years later if I forgot to include some things in my thesis?

Tags: thesis, data, errors-erratum

I graduated 3 years ago with a MS degree and a thesis. I recently discovered that I forgot to include some data - tables and list of datasets. All my final analysis has been included. Can there be some problem about this in the future?
I have a couple of sentences such as : "For the list of datasets used in this experiment, see table xx". I do not have that table. I guess I was in a mad rush at the end and forgot to include those.

Comment: What percentage of MS theses are ever read, after the degree is conferred?   My guess is that the answer to this question means you can sleep easy ;)

Answer (score 19):

> Can there be some problem about this in the future?

What sort of problems do you mean?  It could certainly inconvenience someone in the future if they try to build on your work and have to reconstruct this data.  I'd recommend writing to your advisor to send the additional data tables in case anyone could benefit from them, assuming you don't have in mind doing anything else with them yourself.  You don't have to describe it as material you forgot to include (although, in light of the edited question, there's no way of saving face since you referred to it in the thesis as if it were included).  Instead, you could reasonably say something like "While going through old files, I discovered some potentially useful material that never made it into my master's thesis, which I've attached to this e-mail.  Feel free to make use of it if any future students work on related projects."

On the other hand, you don't need to worry about being punished or having your degree revoked, assuming there was no dishonesty or fraud involved.  There's always more material you could have included in your thesis but didn't, and this is not relevant once the thesis has been approved.  Omissions or even mistakes won't invalidate your degree.

Comment: I think this advice is spot on -- no dishonesty or fraud, then don't worry about it.  There are more important things in life than a master's thesis.  Time to move on ...

Comment: In addition, if your thesis is on line someplace that you control, you might include an "addendum" with the tables.

Answer (score 14):

If you are asking, "Can somebody claim my degree is improper?" then no, you are in no danger.  You really did the work and advisor and your institution have accepted the work as worthy of an MS degree.  Your degree is real and solid.

If you are asking, "Can somebody have real problems trying to build on my work?" then yes, it could be a real problem.  If you want to be a good scientific citizen, then you should get in touch with your advisor or the department staff and find out how to add a correction; in these days of digital documents, it should be possible.

Comment: @phresnel There is no allegation of plagiarism or dishonour here, or any suggestion that the asker's university is "foul". As such, I find your comment rather out of line.

Comment: @phresnel I don't think there's any reason to assume misconduct from the OP's question.

Comment: Even if the university cannot allow a correction to an approved thesis, you could post on-line either or both of a corrected copy or a short note containing the missing items. If those works clearly and completely reference your thesis, anyone trying to build on the thesis is likely to find them.

Comment: @dirkk: Just not prominent ones was what I meant with "public cases". While I don't see how the linked article answers whether a title can be revoked (maybe I did not read hard enough) I realise my knowledge is too limited for a serious discussion. Sorry to anyone, going to delete my comment noise.